# #1054 - Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, mysql-error-1054

I have this query in mysql database:

```
INSERT INTO `table1`( `text1`, `text2`, `link` )

SELECT 
    `text1`,
    `text2``,
    `link`

FROM `table2`

WHERE `table1`.`code` = `table2`.`code`;
```

I get an error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'table1.code' in 'where clause'
```

What am I doing wrong? I have no aliases, I tried `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`, I tried `INNER JOIN` but no success. My `code` columns have no indices.

Comment: Unclear. Either use another copy of `table1` in SELECT part or use UPDATE - depends on logic.

Comment: This query makes no sense at all. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Claus Bönnhoff There are some rows with repetitve data and I wanted to get through more easily. Ma3x answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should show also the structure of `table2` to let us help you better.

Otherwise, the error is due to the lack of `table1` in your query.
As `code` is not present in your `INSERT` statement I may assume that it is an autoincrement field.

Your query (I suppose, as I can't see the definition of `table2`, as wrote before), could be

```sql
SELECT
    t2.text1,
    t2.text2,
    t2.link
FROM table2 AS t2
    INNER JOIN table1 AS t1 ON (t1.code = t2.code)
;
```

If the link between `table1` and `table2` is 1-to-many or many-to-many, just add a `DISTINCT` after the `SELECT` keyword to avoid duplicated results or change your query in

```sql
SELECT
    t2.text1,
    t2.text2,
    t2.link
FROM table2 AS t2
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 'x'
    FROM table1 AS t1
    WHERE t1.code = t2.code
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Ma3x. Both methods work. I don't know what I did wrong with my INNER JOIN. Anyway, This is it :)